# Why is my kendo ui grid not reading the assigned datasource-action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI grid, with a clientrow template, looking like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.UnitDetails)
      .Name("grid")
      .DataSource(ds => ds
                            .Ajax()
                            .Read(read => read.Action("Get", "Home"))
                            .AutoSync(true)
                            .PageSize(5)
                            .ServerOperation(false)
      )
      .RowAction(row =>
          {
              if (row.DataItem.ViewUnitContract.Disabled)
              {
                  row.HtmlAttributes["style"] = "color: gray";
              }
          })
      .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate(" ").Title("Well Site");
              columns.Bound(p => p.ViewUnitContract.Name).Title("Unit Name").Width(200);                      
              columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate(" ").Title("Well");
              columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate(" ").Title("Run").Width(75);
              columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate(" ").Title("Task").Width(250);
              columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate(" ").Title("Activity").Width(150); ;
              columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate(" ").Width(60).Title("Status");
              columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate(" ").Title("Depth (m)").Width(75);
              columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate(" ").Title("Speed (m/min)").Width(75);
              columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate(" ").Width(250).Title("Weight (kg)");                      
          })
      .ClientRowTemplate(Html.Partial("_ClientRowTemplate", Model).ToHtmlString())
      .Sortable())
```

And a controller, looking like this:

```
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using SomeName.Xplorer.Library.Controllers;
using SomeName.Xplorer.Services.Models;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using UnitContract = SomeName.Xplorer.Services.UnitService.UnitContract;

        public class HomeController : BaseController
        {
            private HomeViewModel Model { get; set; }

            [Authorize]
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                UnitContract[] listOfUnitsFromService = UnitClient.GetListOfUnits(true, "");

                Model = new HomeViewModel
                            {
                                UnitDetails = GenerateUnitDetails(listOfUnitsFromService.ToList()),
                            };

                return View(Model);
            }

            public ActionResult Get([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
            {
                UnitContract[] listOfUnitsFromService = UnitClient.GetListOfUnits(true, "");

                Model = new HomeViewModel
                            {
                                UnitDetails = GenerateUnitDetails(listOfUnitsFromService.ToList()),
                            };

                return Json(Model.UnitDetails.ToDataSourceResult(request));
            }
        }
```

And finally, my scripts:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.716/jquery.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.716/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.716/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
```

My question is, why doesn't the grid actually use the "Get" action? Whenever I debug, it just fires off the "Index" action, and that's it. Am I missing something here? :)

Comment: Just check that you add this `Jquery-1.8.1.min.js` file in your view. What ever version that you use in your project.I think that is your problem it's not hit to your `Get` action because i have same problem.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but that does not seem to solve the problem. I've edited my post to include the scripts used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw a couple of things:

1. Your grid is initially server bound. It won't make a request until you page/sort/filter etc. This is easily fixable:

   ```
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.UnitDetails)
   ```

   should be

   ```
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<UnitDetail>()
   ```
2. You are including jQuery twice. This is redundant. Include only one.

Comment: Thank you! :) This seem to have solved the problem - initially. Right now I'm just awaiting some work to be done on the service providing the grid with the data :) Will accept the answer once it has been fixed and implemented (If it works properly :))

Comment: Actually, would you be able to assist me with a few more things, @AtanasKorchev?

Comment: @AtanasKorchev Could you please answer to my problem also. I am getting the issue in rendering the detail template. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39407318/kendo-grid-detail-template-datasource-read-is-not-firing-the-controller-acti